# How do I get rid of quest-related weapons and armor that I no longer need?

Tags: divinity-2-ego-draconis

Items like Barnabus' Mace and Arben's Sword are quest drops that I no longer need but are cluttering up my inventory. I can neither send them to my battle tower, nor sell them, nor delete them. Is there a way to remove them from my inventory at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point in the game, it will remove all the unnecessary quest items from your inventory. I will not give any spoilers, but other than that, there are no direct ways to remove quest items.